# How to fully center a nav bar using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

Still quite a newbie and would appreciate some guidance as this keeps happening on my projects.

I create a nav bar using display: flex - I think I have center aligned everything, but it's moving off to the right.

I was expecting the nav to be center aligned because of the following properties.

```
.navlist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navlist li {
  padding: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

But I get slightly off centre result

[Please check my codepen](https://codepen.io/LauraBizzle/pen/XWVjZZG?editors=1100)

I've also tried margin: auto but still can't figure it out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by slightly right? It seems centered to me

Comment: Hi Buzz - It was only very slightly by 20px - thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in your CSS and it should work fine.

```
.navlist li:first-child {padding-left: 0;}
```

The reason your nav is a little off-center is that it is adding left padding of 20px based on your code so the nav shifts 20px towards the right.

Hope this answer is helpful!

Comment: Thanks so much for this, really appreciate you taking the time to look! Worked perfectly. I didn't realise there would be padding on these automatically.

Comment: Happy to Help you! All the best with your website!

Answer (score 0):

Added a slight change to your code, see if it is what you're expecting

```
.navlist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this for me. This solution didn't work for me but I have found the answer :)